# how to change version of clojure when use La Clojure plugin with IntelliJIDEA

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea

I am using La Clojure within IntelliJIDEA for program development.
when I installed La Clojure(0.4.216), the default version of clojure is 1.3. but I want to use clojure 1.4, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to get jar with clojure version 1.4. You can download in from [here](http://clojure.org/downloads). Unzip it and find `clojure-1.4.0.jar`.
Now you can manually change clojure lib when you create project like here:
[image]
Press `Create` button and choose clojure-1.4.0

If you want to modify existing project, press `File -> Project structure -> Libraries`. **Delete** existing lib (1.3.0) and add new library with clojure 1.4.0:

[image]